# IE block file download but Firefox allows even if setting does not allow in Squid/pfsense

Tags: proxy, squid, pfsense

I have enabled the setting in squid (in pfsesnse) where any file which is greater than 50MB should not be downloaded.

I tried downloading in IE and it comes with error that security setting does not allow you to download that file.

But when i tried same in FF it allows me to download any file size.

Why does Firefox bypass the proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Firefox setup to use the proxy?  Can it get to the internet without using the Proxy? (the answer seems to be yes.  Check the Firefox preferences, specifically Advanced --> Network --> Settings.   By default, Firefox does not use or detect proxies (at least my local copy does not).

Comment: I have manually inserted proxy setting like http 192.168.1.1 and port 3128 but still it downloads everything

Comment: Try restarting Firefox, and clearing the Firefox cookies/cache.